# ios parsing a text file

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a comma delimited file I need to parse. It looks like the this:

`... "John", "Smith", "New York", "10038" ...`

I'm handling about 1000 of these records per file. My plan is to parse them into a `dictionary`.

From what I've found so far, I should be using an `NSInputStream`. My current code looks like this:

## firstViewController.m

```
...
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    GruParser *stream = [[GruParser alloc] init];
    [stream parse:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"gru"]];
}
...
```

## GruParser.m

```
#import "GruParser.h"

@implementation GruParser

-(id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)parse:(NSString *)path {
    NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:path];
    //NSInputStream *stream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"]];

    [stream setDelegate:self];
    [stream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [stream open];
    NSLog(@"%@", @"parse");
}

-(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"stream event");
}

@end
```

`main.m` crashes at line 16 (BAD_ACCESS) and since I'm a 4.2 debugging noob I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. However, the log says "stream". I'm pretty sure I'm crashing on `[stream open]`. Any advice for next steps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GruParser *stream = [[GruParser alloc] init];` instead of `GruParser *stream = [GruParser alloc];` - you create an uninitialized object, which leads to a crash.

Comment: I added that (to my code and to my edit), but I'm still getting the same console as well as the same crash.

Comment: Can you paste the exact output from the console?

Comment: You have to call `dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` as well.

Comment: True, but that won't be the cause of the crash. @Jackson - can we please have the full crash message?

Comment: I'm on LLDB so the output is just the log messages (which now is just "parse"). Call me a n00b for being confused about this, but how do I do what you're needing me to do? I mostly just use `NSLog` to "debug".

Comment: Can you switch to GDB and give the output then?